# Slide menu item down and up on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've created this burger menu:

```js
function menuToggle() {
    var x = document.getElementById("burgerMenu");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
:root {
    /* Static Colors*/
    --clr-heading-footer: #4C5BA0;
    --clr-button: #4C5BA0;
    --clr-nav-color: #8D90A1;
    /* Dark Theme */
    --clr-bg-dark: #2F2F35;
    --clr-card-bg-dark: #3A3B41;
    --clr-card-body-text-dark: #8D90A1;
    --clr-card-title-text-dark: #D3D3D9;
    --clr-nav-activ-color-dark: #D3D3D9;
    --clr-nav-hover-color-dark: #D3D3D9;
    /* (Default) Light Theme */
    --clr-bg-light: #E1E1E1;
    --clr-nav-activ-color-light: #3A3B41;
    --clr-nav-hover-color-light: #3A3B41;
    /* (Default) Set Colors */
    --foreground: var(--clr-bg-dark);
    --background: var(--clr-bg-light);
    --activ-mode-icon: var(--light-sun);
    --activ-hover-mode-icon: var(--light-hover-sun);
    --selected-nav-page: var(--clr-nav-activ-color-light);
    --hover-nav: var(--clr-nav-hover-color-light);
    /* (Default) Page Settings */
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    padding: 0% 12%;
}


body {
    background: var(--background);
    color: var(--foreground);
}

.logo-style {
    /* Logo Style */
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 2.438rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    color: #4C5BA0;
}


/*
    Navigation
*/

.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: none !important;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.topnav button {
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.topnav a {
    color: var(--clr-nav-color);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.09rem 0.30rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.063rem;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    color: var(--hover-nav);
}

.topnav a.active {
    color: var(--selected-nav-page);
}

.right-nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 0.625rem;
    align-items: center;
}

.topnav-menu {
    /* Burger Menu Content*/
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0.09rem 0.30rem;
    background-color: darkblue;
}

.topnav-menu ul {
    /* Burger Menu Content*/
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.topnav-menu a {
    color: var(--clr-nav-color);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.09rem 0.30rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.063rem;
}

.topnav-menu a:hover {
    color: var(--hover-nav);
}

.topnav-menu a.active {
    color: var(--selected-nav-page);
}


/*
    Navigation Burger Menu
*/

.line-one {
    width: 1.875rem;
}

.line-two {
    width: 1.875rem;
}

.line-three {
    width: 1.875rem;
}

.burger-menu div {
    width: 1.875rem;
    height: 0.25rem;
    background-color: var(--clr-nav-color);
    margin: 0.313rem 0;
    border-radius: 1.563rem;
}

.burger-menu {
    width: 1.875rem;
}

.burger-menu:hover div {
    width: 1.875rem;
    background-color: var(--hover-nav);
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
    <div class="left-nav">
        <a href="#home"><p class="logo-style">Metrics</p></a>
    </div>
    <div class="right-nav">
        <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
        <a href="#archives">Archives</a>
        <a href="#coverage">Coverage</a>
        <button type="button" class="dark-mode-toggle disp_mode nav-icon" id="dark-mode-toggle"></button>
        <a href="#burger-menu" class="burger-menu" onclick="menuToggle()">
            <div class="line-one"></div>
            <div class="line-two"></div>
            <div class="line-three"></div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Burger Menu Hidden By Default Untill menuToggle() is activated -->
<div class="topnav-menu" id="burgerMenu" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#item1">item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item2">item2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item3">item3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to de is to make this burger menu `<ul>` items, slideDown like this code, and it should also slide up on second click.

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("wrapper").style.height = "240px";
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
    transition:height 1s ease-out;
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.slideMeDown {
    font-size:24px;
    background: #4679bd;
    color:white;
    width:50%;
    height:200px;
    padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Click to slideDown!</button>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="slideMeDown">cool!</div>
</div>
```

How can this be achieved? I can't seem to make it work, when I try to merge these two codes together? And I dont know how to make it slide up, or it that just `ease-in`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to toggle the height of the element rather than the `display` css property. If you toggle from `display: block;` to `display: none;` you cannot use the `transition` property, because it's just siwtching from visible to invisible.

The logic behind your second snippet is that the `div` element is never hidden, rather they play with the height of the element. When the element `height` equals `0` it gives the illusion that it has disappeared but it has not.

When you toggle the height then you can add a transition to the change made by JS.

**Note:** `overflow: hidden;` is necessary to hide the content inside the element. If you don't use it, then the text inside will overflow the `div` element.

### Try and review the following suggested fix

```js
function menuToggle() {
    var list = document.getElementById("list");
    var listElements =  list.childElementCount; 
    var height = 30 * listElements;
    var x = document.getElementById("burgerMenu");
    if (x.style.height === "0px") {
        x.style.height = height + "px";
    } else {
        x.style.height = "0px";
    }
}
```

```css
:root {
    /* Static Colors*/
    --clr-heading-footer: #4C5BA0;
    --clr-button: #4C5BA0;
    --clr-nav-color: #8D90A1;
    /* Dark Theme */
    --clr-bg-dark: #2F2F35;
    --clr-card-bg-dark: #3A3B41;
    --clr-card-body-text-dark: #8D90A1;
    --clr-card-title-text-dark: #D3D3D9;
    --clr-nav-activ-color-dark: #D3D3D9;
    --clr-nav-hover-color-dark: #D3D3D9;
    /* (Default) Light Theme */
    --clr-bg-light: #E1E1E1;
    --clr-nav-activ-color-light: #3A3B41;
    --clr-nav-hover-color-light: #3A3B41;
    /* (Default) Set Colors */
    --foreground: var(--clr-bg-dark);
    --background: var(--clr-bg-light);
    --activ-mode-icon: var(--light-sun);
    --activ-hover-mode-icon: var(--light-hover-sun);
    --selected-nav-page: var(--clr-nav-activ-color-light);
    --hover-nav: var(--clr-nav-hover-color-light);
    /* (Default) Page Settings */
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    padding: 0% 12%;
}


body {
    background: var(--background);
    color: var(--foreground);
}

.logo-style {
    /* Logo Style */
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 2.438rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    color: #4C5BA0;
}


/*
    Navigation
*/

.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: none !important;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.topnav button {
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.topnav a {
    color: var(--clr-nav-color);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.09rem 0.30rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.063rem;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    color: var(--hover-nav);
}

.topnav a.active {
    color: var(--selected-nav-page);
}

.right-nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 0.625rem;
    align-items: center;
}

.topnav-menu {
    /* Burger Menu Content*/
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 1000ms;
    background-color: darkblue;
}

.topnav-menu ul {
    /* Burger Menu Content*/
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.topnav-menu a {
    color: var(--clr-nav-color);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.09rem 0.30rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.063rem;
}

.topnav-menu a:hover {
    color: var(--hover-nav);
}

.topnav-menu a.active {
    color: var(--selected-nav-page);
}


/*
    Navigation Burger Menu
*/

.line-one {
    width: 1.875rem;
}

.line-two {
    width: 1.875rem;
}

.line-three {
    width: 1.875rem;
}

.burger-menu div {
    width: 1.875rem;
    height: 0.25rem;
    background-color: var(--clr-nav-color);
    margin: 0.313rem 0;
    border-radius: 1.563rem;
}

.burger-menu {
    width: 1.875rem;
}

.burger-menu:hover div {
    width: 1.875rem;
    background-color: var(--hover-nav);
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
    <div class="left-nav">
        <a href="#home"><p class="logo-style">Metrics</p></a>
    </div>
    <div class="right-nav">
        <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
        <a href="#archives">Archives</a>
        <a href="#coverage">Coverage</a>
        <button type="button" class="dark-mode-toggle disp_mode nav-icon" id="dark-mode-toggle"></button>
        <a href="#burger-menu" class="burger-menu" onclick="menuToggle()">
            <div class="line-one"></div>
            <div class="line-two"></div>
            <div class="line-three"></div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Burger Menu Hidden By Default Untill menuToggle() is activated -->
<div class="topnav-menu" id="burgerMenu" style="height:0px;">
  <div style="padding-right:5px">
    <ul id="list">
        <li><a href="#item1">item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item2">item2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item3">item3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a good solution and explanation!

Comment: Your welcome. Keep it up!

Comment: is it possible to make the `x.style.height = "150px";` match the amount of elements so it isn't hardcoded to 150px?

Comment: One approach to this would be to count the elements inside the menu list using  `childElementCount` DOM property and then multiply them to the height of these elements, I used `30` for this example. Finally use this height to toggle the style. I edited the code, check it out.